# Apple IpadOS / ios HTML editor which will sync with Amazon AWS S3 buckets

Tags: iphone, ipad, software-recommendation, html, ipados

Hi so I'm looking for an Apple IpadOS / IOS app that'll edit a HTML file stored in an Amazon S3 bucket, and update, and upload it back. I could only find "Code Editor" by Panic for Ipados, but there seems to be no other app to sync to Amazon s3 buckets?

Can anyone suggest me an app or upcoming app? The only other way I can think of is to open a SFTP link to the bucket somehow. Does aws s3 have this feature? Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an app now that does this in iphone and ipad .. Filebrowser for Business, supoorts AWS S3 syncs.

[Link to Apple App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/filebrowser-for-business/id854618029)

Comment: could you add a link to the app page ?

Comment: @ankii done it’s in the answer itself